"anstatt" + Dativ oder Genitiv
According to my sources including Duden, the preposition "anstatt" shall be ideally followed with the Genitiv.
But Duden also mentions that it can be followed by the Dativ in some cases: [anstatt] mit Dativ, wenn der Genitiv formal nicht zu erkennen ist: "anstatt Worten will ich Taten sehen".
So I would have the following questions:

Is there a rule of thumb when to use "anstatt" with Genitiv and when with Dativ?
What is the more common use in everyday practice?
How shall I use "anstatt" in the following translated sentence: "I will give it to her instead of him."? The Genitiv of the masculin pronoun "er" would be "seiner", but it sounds weird to use it here? For instance, would the following translation be correct: "Ich werde es ihr anstatt seiner geben."?


Generally speaking, the Genetive is dying out in favor of the Dativ in everyday language (2.) and this is a particular instance. While old texts and very formal modern ones might still use "Ich werde es ihr an seiner statt geben." (notice that you should divide anstatt), this would sound pretty off (like acting a classical theater) nowadays. "Ich werde es ihr statt ihm geben." is what you would say in this case in any normal conversation or even formal writing.

Dass der Genitiv ausstirbt, habe ich schon vor 40 Jahren gehört. Gibt es dazu empirische Befunde? Ich halte es für ein Gerücht.

@Echsecutor Thanks very much for your answer!
